# What does module.exports do when used in a variable declaration

Tags: node.js, express, var, node-modules, variable-declaration

I was looking at some other people's code, and I saw this line.

```
var app = module.exports = express();
```

Does that mean that app is set to a express, and is simultaneously exported? How does Javascript know how to do this? What is the order of evaluation?

Answer (score 0):

Per the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence), the assignment operator `=` is right-associative, meaning that the operation is executed right-to-left.  So this is the same as writing

```
module.exports = express();
var app = module.exports;
```

Put another way, the result of an assignment operation is the assigned value.